# How to refresh page when onclick() returns false?

Tags: html, onclick

I have a submit button inside a form, I set an onclick() function for the button, like the following,

```
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"Action\" value=\"chgRole\">\n";
    <input type=\"submit\" class=\"submit\" value=\"Change Role\" onclick=\"return chgConfirm()\">";
```

And below is how my chgConfirm() looks like:

```
function chgConfirm(){
        var makechg = false;
        var s= "....";
             (some other operation)

        if (!makechg){
              alert(s);
              return false;
             }
        else {
              var r = confirm(s);
              if (r)
                     return true;
              else
                     return false;
             }
       }
```

What I want to do is that once the chgConfirm() returns false, I want to refresh the original page. I try to change:

```
if(r)
     return true;
else
     window.location(this page);
```

but it doesn't work.

Any good suggestions? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This...

```
 else {
              var r = confirm(s);
              if (r)
                     return true;
              else
                     document.location.reload(true);
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `reload`:

```
window.location.reload();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

Comment: @user1453951 Mine was first. But, no worries. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of window.location, use:

```
    document.location.reload(true);
```